# convert query into nested query

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

how do you convert a join query into a nested query (using "where in" condition)?
for eg how to convert this into a nested query?

```
SELECT student.studentname,
       schedule.subcode,
       AVG(attendance.ispresent)*100 AS Attendance_Status 
FROM student
JOIN attendance
    ON student.usn = attendance.usn
JOIN schedule
    ON schedule.sched_id = attendance.sched_id
WHERE student.usn="4jc14is008"
GROUP BY schedule.subcode
ORDER BY schedule.subcode;
```

Comment: I think a double join might need a doubly nested `WHERE` clause (read: really ugly).  Why would you need to do this, unless you are using something like JPA which requires that format for some reason?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, is it possible to have nested queries which involve 3 tables? what is the syntax of it?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen can you please elaborate about the doubly nesting which you have mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be evaluated as an NLJ ("Nested Loop Join").

1. Look in `student`, filtering on `usn = '...'`.
2. For each such row (probably one in this case), do NLJ into `attendance` to locate any and all rows that satisfy the `ON` given.  This leads to a longer (or shorter) list of rows.
3. For each of the rows in #2, do NLJ into `schedule` based on `ON`.  Now there is a set of rows...
4. Do the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` (these can be done simultaneously since they are identical).  This will deliver no more rows than what #3 gave.  (`GROUP BY` can never increase the number of rows.)

Do *not* rewire the query into `WHERE x IN ( SELECT ... )`, that usually make it run slower.